How can I report cheating in Halo Infinite multiplayer?
If I'm suspecting that a player is cheating during a multiplayer match, how can I report the player for cheating?

Here is how you can do so (In-Game reporting):
On Xbox:

Open the scoreboard by pressing the "View"
button.
Use the left stick or D-pad to highlight the player you want to report.
Press the "A" button to open the player options.
Select the "Report Player" option. Choose the reason for the report
(e.g., cheating, abusive behavior).

On PC:

Press the "Tab" key to open the scoreboard.
Use your mouse to click on the player’s name
Right-click on the player’s name to open the player options.
Select the "Report Player" option. Choose the reason for the report
(e.g., cheating, abusive behavior).


